# JVisualVM does not find my Java process

Tags: java, jvisualvm

I started a Java process with JDK 1.8.0_101 in my user account. The task manager shows me that it is running.

Then I start jvisualvm for the same JDK and same user and cannot see the process. Any ideas?

I am using Windows Server 2012.

Comment: I've found the option -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote to be necessary for JConsole in Java 8... perhaps also for VisualVM?

Answer (score 0):

I started the java process from a console that ran "as administrator". The `jvisualvm` was started without administrator rights. This seemed to be the reason.

Comment: that is, not the same user ?!

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger It was shown with the same user name in the task manager.